# How to load a customView into viewForHeaderInSection and then load resize this by content?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a `UITableView` into my app (Swift, but I explain this example in Objective-c. I load into this `viewForHeaderInSection` the custom view, but this view has dynamic size depends elements.

I'm loading by default a short title and then 6 seconds I change this by a long text. But then 6 seconds when the text change, the size of header ins't resizing.

If I load the text at first time, this change the size by the content, but I need set this text then 6 seconds instead of at first time. I'm trying with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` but the `footerView` isn't resizing with my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SampleCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SampleCell"];
     [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SampleHeader" bundle:nil] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:@"SampleHeader"];

     self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
     self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 10;

     self.tableView.dataSource = self;
     self.tableView.delegate = self;
 }

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
     SampleHeader *header = (SampleHeader * )[tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"SampleHeader"];

     header.label.text = @"Section 1. It has a short title.";

     double delayInSeconds = 6.0;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            header.label.text = @"Section 3. It has a extra large title, the view will grow to addapt follwoing the autolayout constraints that we have set in the interface builder tra large title, the view will grow to addapt follwoing the autolayout constraints that we h tra large title, the view will grow to addapt follwoing the autolayout constraints that we h tra large title, the view will grow to addapt follwoing the autolayout constraints that we h tra large title, the view will grow to addapt follwoing the autolayout constraints that we h";
            [header layoutIfNeeded];
        });
     return header;
}
```

What is the correct way to reload the **header of section** then tableView is loaded? Thanks!

Comment: You're mixing up header and footer in your question. Your code sets `sectionHeaderHeight` and `viewForHeaderInSection`, but you seem to indicate in your question you are interested in the footer. Maybe that's the issue after all?

Comment: Sorry, was a mistake. I have edit my question. I wanted to say header of section

Comment: just set the content in viewforheader in section and use this in height for header in section
headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: width, height: UIView.layoutFittingExpandedSize.height),
                                               withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required, 
                                               verticalFittingPriority: .fittingSizeLevel)